When I type flutter doctor it doesn't show me any thing, SDK version solving failed
when i want to pub get it show me this error , also when i wrote flutter doctor it does not show me any thing like itis loading or some thing
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.1.
Because attendance requires SDK version >=3.22.3 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code 1
i tried to change the environment to this :
sdk: '>=3.22.3 <4.0.0'
but sitll same error

you didn't provide the error message or the entire process clearly

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please run flutter upgrade to update Flutter and Dart to their latest versions. See if it helps. The latest version currently at this writing is 3.4.4 (stable).

the update on my problem: when I want to run my app, it shows an error:                                                   Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.0.
The version solution failed since attendance requires SDK version >=3.22.3 <4.0.0. So, I removed the SDK from my computer and reinstalled it again, but I got the same error.
